# How to cancel GPO which was Set by the Administrator?

Tags: windows-10, active-directory, group-policy

We have four computer labs. Each one has 50 computers. All of them run on Windows 10 Pro. We have decided to use Active Directory. Added all the computers into the domain.

Last week a friend of mine (another admin) have made several changes on the group policies.

One of the biggest problem is all the computers' HDDs are set to 200 MB quota. Now we cannot logon the computers, because the entire disk is full (0 bytes free 200 MB total) and there is not enough space to retrieve user profiles onto the disk.

Then my friend has deleted all the settings on group policies which he made. All the settings are set to default. But again, we cannot update the group policies on the client computers, because the disk seems full.

if I run the command

```
gpupdate /force
```

I get a message says group policy cannot be updated.

For a try, I have reset a computer to factory settings, added into the domain again. It works well now.

And we cannot find another solution other than re-installing Windows one by one. But we have too little time.

I believe that there is a way to rollback/cancel/delete group policies on the clients. So, is there a way to do it or do you have alternative solutions?

Comment: Step 1: Disable your friends account and revoke his administrator access to the network.  Step 2: Restore the last updated installation image from before the group policy change.  Step 3: Accept your friend royally screwed up and there isn't another alternative.

Comment: Because the HDD seems full to all accounts (even the local account), I was unable to open start menu, settings, notifications, etc. I was totally stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have solved the disk quota limit problem. Then after restart, group policy has been updated and now it is good.

The main issue is disability to write the HDD because it seems full. So group policy could not be updated. After changing everything back to old settings on the server, I have focused on the client computers.

Then I,

- Logged on with local administrator
- Opened "This Computer" window
- Right-clicked on "Properties"
- Clicked on the "Quota" Tab
- Clicked on the "Show Quota Settings" Button
- On the openning window, clicked on the button labeled as "Quota Entries..."
- Selected all the quota settings in the list
- Clicked on "Quota -> Properties" from the menu
- Select the "Do not limit disk usage" option on the General tab of Quota Settings ..."
- Closed all the windows clicking "OK" buttons.
- Then checked if the HDD size turned back to its original value (which is 2 TB)
- Then restarted the computer.

After the booting, it updated the group policy and computer is active again.